# have to set port every time in command line when trying to trigger any Perforce command

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I'm new to Perforce, need to work in command line, i'm so confused why all the commands on the tutorial websites all write like `$`p4 command, but I have to add the port every time when try to trigger that command, for an example, for `$`p4 sync, i have to type `$`p4 -p myhost:myport sync every time even after I logged in, if i missed the host and port, like if i just typing `$`p4 sync, the program will just hang in there... anyone can provide some suggestions?

Comment: since I want to automate the process and have only one workspace, I'd rather go with setting environment variables, but if i have multiple workspace, I'd go with P4CONFIG file, thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type:

```
p4 set P4PORT=myhost:myport
```

From that point on, "myhost:myport" will be used as the P4PORT when you run commands.

If you use multiple workspaces/servers, P4CONFIG files make it easy to have different sets of settings (based on your working directory), but for a single value, "p4 set" is a nice persistent one-shot method.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple ways to make `myhost:1666` the default. These are, in the order of decreasing precedence:

1. command-line options (like `-p myhost:1666`)
2. the [`P4CONFIG` file](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4CONFIG.html)
3. environment variables (`%P4PORT%`)
4. on Windows, the registry (use `p4 set P4PORT=myhost:1666` to set it)

See the docs [here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-24024).

In your case, I guess the registry (if on Windows) or the env. var. (if on Linux) is the best option.